# Unable to calculate the date duration and append to the HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:
[My Business Day Calculation](https://jsfiddle.net/0115527/2qucwbgL/1/)

```
<input id="dDate1" type="date">
<input id="dDate2" type="date">
<label id="lbl"></label>

    function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) 
 { // input given as Date objects
    var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
    if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
    var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
    var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
    if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; 
    // adjustment if both days on weekend
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

    if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) 
    {
      iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
    } 
    else 
    {
      iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
    }

    iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

    return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}

var x = calcBusinessDays(new Date(document.getElementById("dDate1")), new Date(document.getElementById("dDate2")));
document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = x;
```

I tried to enter the input date from 2 input fields for calculating the business day. But the label still remains NaN even though I chose the dates.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

according to your [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0115527/2qucwbgL/1/) your first problem is that you should make get values of your dates from inside of your `calcBusinessDays` because you are using `onblur` function of date input( also maybe there would be some other solutions). and your second problem is that in the way that you design your function call, you have to change your label from inside of your function .

there is an example of working code:

```js
 

function calcBusinessDays() 
 { // input given as Date objects
  
dDate1= new Date(document.getElementById("dDate1").value);
dDate2 = new Date(document.getElementById("dDate2").value);
if (isNaN(dDate1) ||isNaN(dDate2)) return;
    var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
    if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
    var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
    var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
    if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; 
    // adjustment if both days on weekend
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

    if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) 
    {
      iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
    } 
    else 
    {
      iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
    }

    iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = iDateDiff + 1;
    return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}
```

```html
<input id="dDate1" type="date" onblur="calcBusinessDays()">
<input id="dDate2" type="date" onblur="calcBusinessDays()">
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you, but what if I wanna exclude the holidays too, I have no idea to write about that!

Comment: sorry but I have no idea about that :(.